# Is "ill-intendedly" a word?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives, adverbs

When an adjective is used to describe an action, a verb, it becomes an adverb and is added a `-ly`. And so, these two sentences should be correct:

> It was an **intended** act.
>
> I **intendedly** did it.

Now, the word `ill-intended` basically refers to something being done with bad/malicious intent, with an evil motive. Can I use the same grammar on this word - can the word `ill-intended` directly replace `intended` in a sentence?

> It was an **ill-intended** act.
>
> I **ill-intendedly** did it.

I can't find descriptions and definitions of `ill-intendedly` when searching, but it seems to be a proper sentence. What is your view on this?

Comment: “I did it with ill intent” is perhaps the more common way that I would think to say this.

Comment: "Maliciously" is a perfectly good word meaning with ill intent.

Answer (score 2):

Because participles can play a role as adjectives, they can be formed into adverbs.

> Drunkenly

is an example that is used with fair frequency. However, the formation of adverbs from perfect participles seems to be rare; what is far more common is the formation of adverbs from present participles. I have no explanation for this; it is simply a personal observation.

> Ill-intendedly

may be grammatical, but it certainly is neither idiomatic nor euphonious. For one thing, "intentionally" forms an equivalent adverb to "intendedly" without forming an adverb from a perfect participle. For another "ill-intended" is a compound of adverb and adjective using an adverb that is very odd in having identical adjectival and adverbial forms.

I think I would say

> I did it with ill intent

using an adverbial phrase rather than a weird adverb.

Comment: From what you are saying, is it correctly understood that `ill-intendedly` is not strictly wrong, but not commonly (never) used?

Comment: I have never heard it or seen it used. In that sense, it is not idiomatic. It does not, as far as I can see, violate any rule on forming words in English. Because there are alternatives to this non-idiomatic word, I'd recommend avoiding it completely.